# How to use include function with print or echo using php

Tags: php

I have tried everything to get a full path printed when I click on the Browse button and I tried to get help from the community:

[Writing the full path of the file when it is browsed using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33130219/writing-the-full-path-of-the-file-when-it-is-browsed-uisng-php)

But apparently for security reasons it is not possible. So I have tried to find a way around it. Since I know the location of the files that I am browsing (the user doesn't know it) I have copied the URL in a text file and used inclue to read the URL from the text file and put it in a text box on my webpage.

```
<input name="A" type="text" VALUE="<?PHP echo include("/var/www/html/test.txt");?>" size="20">
```

Something odd happens in the text box and there is always a "1" added for some reason at the end of the URL. For example, instead of

```
www/htdocs/inc
```

I get

```
www/htdocs/inc1
```

in the text box.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`include`](http://php.net/include) statement includes and evaluates the specified file. It's used when you want to include additional PHP code. In this case, you're just wanting to output what's in a text file, so you don't need `include`. You can just use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) instead:

```
VALUE="<?PHP echo file_get_contents("/var/www/html/test.txt");?>"
```