# Direct the browser to choose only from one directory

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is there a way to direct the browser to choose only from a certain directory?

This is my script for the browser:

```
Data Save Directory:<input name="datasavedir" type="file" id="fileUpload" value="Browse">
```

I am trying to restrict the user to only choose a file form one directory. Is there a way to do this using PHP or Javascript?

Comment: " on **my** computer" - O.o ?

Comment: You won't be able to, and the idea won't work anyhow as users can have different directories tree depending on a lot of variable (OS, users, company restrictions etc..)

Comment: _" trying to restrict the user to only choose a file form one directory. Is there a way to do this using PHP or Javascript?"_ No, this is not possible

Comment: after all, it's their own computers!

Comment: The file input cannot accept values for security reasons. What you could possibly do is to validate the path upon submission.

Comment: @LucasRodrigues validate `"C:\fakepath\myfile.ext"` ?

Comment: @LucasRodrigues: No you can't.  All you can "validate" is the file name.

Comment: @MaryE What is purpose ? Is requirement to restrict file selection to specific file type ?

Comment: @guest271314 I was asked to print out the path directory to the file that is chosen by user. I did my research and apprently it can not be done due to security reasons.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33130219/writing-the-full-path-of-the-file-when-it-is-browsed-uisng-php so I am trying to find a way around it and define a known path that can be browsed and since I know file path I can print it out

Comment: @MaryE: How would you even define a *known* path?  You have no idea what's on my computer.

Comment: _"trying to find a way around it and define a known path that can be browsed"_ "browsed" by whom , what ? , How "browsed" ?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Let's assume I know. Would it be possible.I am working on  a local server.

Comment: @MaryE: No, it's not possible.  You cannot read/set the path on a *user's* computer when they upload a file.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I know all about your `Net#LocalServer::HiddenDrive.$.Secret.Stash` directory

Comment: @PaulS.: I have no idea what you're talking about :-P  (/*renames secret stash*/)

Comment: @MaryE: Can you explain in the question *exactly* what you are trying to do?  Maybe there's something you *can* do, but we can't suggest anything without knowing what your goal here is.

Comment: @MaryE Is requirement for user to upload file to an interface , e.g., a `textarea` element, edit file, user then downloads same file , modified by edits, to overwrite original uploaded file at user filesystem ?

Comment: @RocketHazmat The GUI that I am designing should be able to let the user saves his/her data in a file. The user should be able to see the path of the file that he has chosen. This path should be printed out

Comment: @MaryE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30563157/edit-save-self-modifying-html-document-format-generated-html-javascript ?

Comment: @RocketHazmat     Since I could not do this, I have thought to restrict the user to save his/her data to a certain file that I allow them too. This way I know already the file path and I can print it out.

Comment: @MaryE: That's not possible.  It *may* be with ActiveX, but then it would only work in IE.

Comment: OK I am working with UBUNTU

Comment: @MaryE When user uploads file, `File` object should have property `name` , when user downloads same file , for example, after editing, could set `download` attribute of `a` element to file name of previously uploaded `File` object. If user clicks "Save" when `a` clicked , original file in user filesystem should be overwritten by new file with same file name

Comment: @guest271314 what is important to this project is to set the file path print out. For example: Desktop/mydirectory/text.txt

Comment: @MaryE Could add `input` for user to insert path. That would be user prerogative to input path on their filesystem. Cannot force user to disclose folders, files, file paths on user filesystem. Why is printing file path important ?

Comment: @guest271314 OK will do that..thanks

Comment: @guest271314 Because another GUI will read the data form this file and generate a graph from it

Comment: @guest271314   and it needs the file path and I need to save the path somehow

Comment: @guest271314: But the user would still have to browse to the folder to save the file.

Comment: @MaryE: I don't think any of this is actually possible.  You cannot read/write to files on the filesystem without the user selecting it in a OS-controlled popup.

Comment: @RocketHazmat _"But the user would still have to browse to the folder to save the file."_ Yes, exact application not clear ; though if user decides to upload a certain file path on their filesystem, at their own discretion, could do so.  Note: Not recommended

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot restrict the client from choosing directories. The user will be able to choose from any directory from the computer. It's not up to you to decide what the user can view in his/her computer.

Comment: Is there a way to have a default directory opened up when the browse button is hit?

Comment: @MaryE: No, there isn't.  What directory would you even want?  Mac OS X, Windows, and Linux all use *different* directory trees.

Comment: I was asked to print out the path directory to the file that is chosen by user. I did my research and apprently it can not be done due to security reasons.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33130219/writing-the-full-path-of-the-file-when-it-is-browsed-uisng-php

Comment: So I thought maybe I can define a known path and then I can print out that.

Comment: What is purpose of retrieving file path of selected file from user filesystem ?

Comment: I am working on a local server. So I want them to be able to save their work in a known directory. Like desktop.

Comment: _"am working on a local server. So I want them to be able to save their work in a known directory."_ `input type="file"` uploads file . Not certain what "save their work" means ? Can include `js` , description of application at Question ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
inputs[1].onclick = function() {
  console.log(inputs[0].value)
}
```

```html
<label>Input file path (at own discretion): <input type="text" /></label>
<input type="button" value="click" />
```